# A strange format of string in front-end

Tags: discussion

I swear nobody can run this code. (I just copy it from my font-end into *SE* comment. Then I found I cannot run it anymore).

`Import["‌​http://i.stack.imgur‌​.com/MXuoa.png"]`

But this can

`Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXuoa.png"]`

What's happen on this web-site address? How to forbid it? And how to run it normally?

Comment: @Szabolcs Little annoying qeustion..I think it should be fixed by *SE*

Comment: Well, it's done on purpose. Which comment did you copy this from?

Comment: @Szabolcs Just try this `Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[Flatten[ImageData[Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/zteoL.png"],Byte]]]]`

Comment: Try inserting a space here and there. `Uncompress[
 FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/zteoL.png"], 
    Byte]]]]`  I just pasted this directly from the front end, and spaces were inserted automatically. According to that meta post, these characters will be inserted every 60 characters that did not have a space.

Comment: @Szabolcs and yode, I found it appropriate to migrate and mark it as a duplicate. Let me know if you disagree or you think I missed something.

Comment: No,thanks for operation. :)